# How to create a modern-looking circular score counter using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How can I create a "score counter" like the one in the picture, so that I can set a maximum for any circle and add as much concentric circles (counters regarding the same thing) as I want? The diameter of a circle should fit its content, so that we can use little or big items inside (e.g 4790K and G32558 in this case).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Edit:** An amended version where `cnt radius` is really a radius!

Here is a solution using:

- `cnt radius` key to fix the intern radius,
- `cnt min line width` key to set the width of circles,
- `cnt max line width` key to set the width of arcs,
- `cnt` key to add a new modern counter,
- `cnt label` style to customize the central label.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  cnt radius/.store in=\minradius,
  cnt min line width/.store in=\minlinewidth,
  cnt max line width/.store in=\maxlinewidth,
  cnt add val/.code n args={3}{% arguments: color, diameter, proportion
    \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
    \draw[line width={\maxlinewidth*.8},draw=#1,line cap=round,
    ]
    (\tikzlastnode) ++(90:{(#2)/2}) arc(90:{90-((#3)*360)}:{(#2)/2});
    \end{pgfinterruptpath}
  },
  cnt/.style args={#1 color #2 with #3}{% arguments: number, color, proportion
    circle,inner sep=0,node contents={},draw=#2,line width=\minlinewidth,
    minimum size={2*\minradius+(#1*2*\maxlinewidth)},append after command={
      \pgfextra{\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/cnt add val={#2}{2*\minradius+(#1*2*\maxlinewidth)}{#3}}}
    },
  },
  cnt label/.style={text=#1,font=\sffamily\bfseries,yscale=1.2,align=flush center},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[cnt radius=1.5cm,cnt min line width=.5mm,cnt max line width=3mm]
    \node[cnt=1 color lime with .7];
    \node[cnt=2 color orange with .8];
    \node[cnt=3 color cyan!50!black with .9];
    \node[cnt label=cyan!50!black,text width=3cm]{\Huge 4790K};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

**One solution**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
% 
\def\decal {0.4cm}
\def\stepC {0.25cm}

% Current et max values
\def\VoltageC {1.3}
\def\VoltageMax {1.5}
\def\TempC {6.5}
\def\TempMax {8.0}
\def\PwC {4800sp}
\def\PwMax {5000sp}

% width for text inside
\def\textWIDTH {5cm}


%command for plotting  circles
\newcommand{\CircleScore}[4]{%
  \draw (orig) circle (#1);
  \draw[line width=5pt,#4] (orig) ++(90:#1) arc (90:90-360*#2/#3:#1);
}

\node[anchor=center,at=(orig),text width=\textWIDTH,text centered,rectangle](txtC){\textbf{blablalalallalalalalallaalalK}};

%plot circles
\CircleScore{\textWIDTH/2+\decal}{\VoltageC}{\VoltageMax}{green!50!black}
\CircleScore{\textWIDTH/2+\decal+\stepC}{\TempC}{\TempMax}{orange!50!black}
\CircleScore{\textWIDTH/2+\decal+2*\stepC}{\PwC}{\PwMax}{blue!50!black}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Details:**
The fit is not automatic. You must specify the value of `\textWIDTH`. For other values of data, you must change values of the variables `\VoltageC`, `\VoltageMax`, `\TempC`, `\TempMax`, `\PwC` and `\PwMax`.
This solution can be improve.

NB: I use `sp` unit when I specify "large" integer for avoiding `dimension too large` error

**Result:**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5):

Alternative solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
     start angle = 90,
    Score/.style = {name=#1,
                   shape=circle, inner sep=0pt, %draw,
                   font=\Large}
                   ]
    \def\scoreWIDTH{10mm}
\node[Score=c1] {4790K};
%score list
\foreach[count=\xi from 0] \i/\j in {red/0.9, blue/0.7, yellow/0.8}
{
\draw[\i]   (c1) circle (\scoreWIDTH+1.2*\xi mm);
\draw[line width=1mm,\i]
            (c1) + (0,\scoreWIDTH+1.2*\xi mm) arc[radius=\scoreWIDTH+1.2*\xi mm,
                                              delta angle=-\j*360];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Your score list and desired color you put in `\foreach` loop, line width is defined as parameter of `\draw`. For more color you need add `\color` or better `\xcolor` package and select desired color.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to draw this lines with [`wheelchart`](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) help:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}

%#1-Percentatge
%#2-Radius
%#3-Color
\newcommand{\wheelline}[3]{%
\wheelchart[data={}, radius={#2-\WCvarC}{#2+\WCvarC},
slices start arc={1}{0}, slices end arc={1}{0}
]{%
#1/#3/0.15,
{100-#1}/#3/0.05%
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelline{65}{2}{lime}
\wheelline{75}{2.4}{orange}
\wheelline{85}{2.8}{cyan!80!black}
\node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\Huge, text=cyan!80!black] {4790K};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]