# Fancy progress circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I would like to make with tikz three progress circles like these + a "Medium level" one wich is half full.

[image]

I've found this answer ([Draw a progress circle around text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268327/draw-a-progress-circle-around-text)) but I don't know how to adapt it in order to have the spaces between the dark grey-colored sector and the light grey-colored one.

Thanks very much in advance to anyone who's able to help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only small modification is required to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268335/28557) to achieve the desired result.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\outerradius}
\newlength{\innerradius}
\setlength{\outerradius}{2cm}
\setlength{\innerradius}{1.5cm}

\newcommand{\progresscircle}[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[black!80] (0,0) circle (\outerradius);
    \fill[gray!70,draw=white,line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (0, \outerradius+1pt)
      arc (90:90-3.6*#1:\outerradius+1pt) -- (0,0);
    \fill[white] (0,0) circle (\innerradius);
    \node[align=center, text width = 2*\innerradius] (0,0) { #2};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\progresscircle{85.34}{\textbf{Test 1} \\ seems okay}

\progresscircle{41.57}{\textbf{Test 2}\\ this\\too\\}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very very much! Is there a way so that I can write over two lines inside the circle?

Comment: @luciadefinetti Please see the edited answer

Comment: As not said --- it works great now, thank you!

Comment: @luciadefinetti I also can't think of any reason why it should not work. Check if overleaf is listing any error or not.  (You can find the option to see error/log somewhere on top bar in overleaf.)

Answer (score 4):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The percentage is defined by `\n`.

The gap between the slices is obtained with the key `gap`.

The value is given by the first variable which is `\n` for the first slice and `100-\n` for the second slice.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\def\n{75}
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  data=,
  gap,
  middle=\textbf{ENGLISH}\\Advanced level,
  radius={1.5}{2},
  start angle=-90
]{%
  \n/darkgray,
  {100-\n}/gray!50%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```