# How to create a Pie like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I need to create this Pie diagram

```
\mypie{x,y,82}{basecolor}{Fillcolor}{Some Text,L}
```

x= radius of first circle, y= radius of second concentric circle(This is to control the size of the circle and the thickness between two concentric circles, Feel free to provide another way to provide values if you wish)

- 82 is the percent shall come as 82% as shown in the middle written using Fillcolor
- "Some Text" will position itself relatively centered either Left or Right of the Pie[L as in here Left, R should make the text appear Right]
  Here Base color is Gray and Fill color is green as in the picture [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4g02BqzkHIhb1REeHlWT3RuRjQ/view?usp=sharing).

Addons:

```
 \mypie{x,y,82}{basecolor}{Fillcolor}{Some Text,L}{3D}
```

- Give an optional switch to get a 3D Pipe like effect of the above pie, a rounded pipe like effect rather than the above Flat 2D effect.

Comment: and what is wrong with `pgf-pie` ?

Comment: The `3D` option is kinda of hard to implement, because it wouldn't be a simple switch, you'd have to redraw the pie from scratch.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to create a modern-looking circular score counter using tikz?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225949/14500)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, here's a custom solution with Tikz and `xstring`. The command goes like this:

```
\percentage[ <optional> ]{ <radius,perc> }{ <color1,color2> }{ <label,position> }
```

1. The `optional` argument takes a length such as `1.5mm` and so on. Default is `2pt`.
2. The second argument takes actually two values as shown, comma separated. The `radius` determines the size of the circles (not their width), while the percentage calculates the progress circle bar and of course, the central label.
3. The third argument takes the colors, below first, progress bar second.
4. The last argument takes the label along with its position. In this case I left the default position names because it'd be pointless to just rename them for this command. They are the following:

   - above, right, left, below
   - above right/left, below right/left
   - You can also use arbitrary angles, such as: 90 (above), 45 (above right) and so on.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\percentage[4][2pt]{%
\tikz{
    \StrBehind{#2}{,}[\perc]
    \StrBefore{#2}{,}[\lwidth]
    \StrBehind{#3}{,}[\percl]
    \StrBefore{#3}{,}[\backl]
    \StrBehind{#4}{,}[\pos]
    \StrBefore{#4}{,}[\lbl]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\endangle{-(\perc/100*360)+90}
    \draw[\backl, line width=#1] (90:\lwidth mm) arc (90:-270:\lwidth mm); 
    \draw[\percl, line width=#1] (90:\lwidth mm) arc (90:\endangle:\lwidth mm);
    \pgfmathsetmacro\halfw{\lwidth/2}
    \node[circle, 
        minimum size=\halfw mm, 
        text=\percl,
        label={\pos:\lbl}
        ] {$\perc\%$};
}
}

\begin{document}
\percentage{7,64.90}{gray!20,green}{Some text,above right}
\end{document}
```