# Circular Gauge Plot in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, tikz-pic

Is there a way to create a circular gauge plot in LaTeX using Tikz library or PgfPlots?

I found a way to create a horizontal gauge plot, but can't find the circular one?

[image: circular gauge plot LaTeX]

Thank you.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225949/

Comment: I don't know about PGFplots but that can easily created with TikZ alone. Is it always one arc or are there multiple? Maybe one of the pie-chart packages would help here.

Comment: @Zarko, thank you so much. That is exactly what I was looking for. I searched around a lot, but I guess the question used different kind of description, so could not find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another thread. It was asked with different description than Gauge plot. Here is the link. (Thanks to @Zarko)

[How to create a modern-looking circular score counter using tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225949/how-to-create-a-modern-looking-circular-score-counter-using-tikz)